# Android. Стили. colorPrimary

Tags: java, android, style, color, android-style

У меня в приложении несколько стилей.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Toolbar</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>

<style name="GreenStyle">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_green_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="BrownStyle">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_brown</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_brown_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="TealStyle">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_teal</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_teal_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Main.Green" parent="GreenStyle" />

<style name="AppTheme.Main.Brown" parent="BrownStyle" />

<style name="AppTheme.Main.Teal" parent="TealStyle" />
```

При запуске активити я устанавливаю выбранную в настройках тему, например:

```
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Main_Green);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);
```

Вот выдержка из colors.xml

```
<color name="accent">#FFC107</color>
<color name="primary_green">#4CAF50</color>
<color name="primary_green_dark">#388E3C</color>
<color name="primary_brown">#795548</color>
<color name="primary_brown_dark">#5D4037</color>
```

Цвета элементов на активити устанавливаются корректно, все хорошо
Однако если я хочу "вручную" перекрасить какой то элемент и обращаюсь к свойству primaryColor, система берет цвет primaryColor не установленный в моем стиле, а из colorPrimary "по умолчанию". В моем случае это синий цвет.

Обращаюсь например так:

```
setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

или так:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:endColor="@color/accent" />
```

обращение @color/accent отрабатывает корректно, так как он так оперделен в файле colors.xml

Однако если обращаться к акцент цвету через @colors/colorAccent, то акцент цвет так же скидывается на цвет "по умолчанию", а не используется цвет из моего стиля.

Как работать с цветами через "colorAccent" и "colorPrimary", чтобы они цеплялись из моего стиля?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В стилях вы определяете атрибуты, кои содержат ссылки на ресурсы цветов.

В вашем коде вы берете цвет из ресурсов цветов.

Вам же надо получать цвет по ссылке, хранящейся в атрибуте:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="?colorPrimary"
    android:endColor="?colorAccent" />
```

При этом имейте в виду, что в `xml-drawable` нельзя использовать атрибуты в качестве цветов на `API<21`. В этом случае вам придётся создать атрибут-ссылку и в каждом стиле указать ссылку на отдельный файл `xml-drawable`

---

Программно же получить цвет из атрибута нетривиальная задача, но вот вам рабочий код:

```
public static int getColor(Context ctx, int addressInRClass)
{
    int colorId;
    int[] attrs = new int[]{addressInRClass};
    TypedArray ta = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    colorId = ta.getColor(0, Color.GRAY);
    ta.recycle();

    return colorId;
}
```

Вызывать так:

```
int colorPrimary = getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary);
```